# Write to CSV file but use a different row each time in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I am creating a data frame called "std_summary" which does a few calculations and creates a data frame. I am looping this for the data sets I want to analyze, so the script will go through and create a new csv file with the data analyzed. Each data set will always have the same columns, but the rows can vary. What I want to do is write this to one csv file instead of overwriting to itself, like it is now, or creating a new one. How would I do that? What I want to do is run through the calculations and create the data frame. Then when writing the data frame to the csv file, skip the rows from the last one and write after.
Here is my code now..let me know if you need anything else!

```
std_summary = ddply(stds[!stds$outlier,],.(well_96,concentration),summarize,
mean_int = mean(int,na.rm=T),
std_int = sd(int,na.rm=T),
prec_cv = (std_int*100/mean_int))
std_summary$r_squared = stds.cod
std_summary$slope = stds.lm$coefficients[2]
std_summary$intercept = stds.lm$coefficients[1]
std_summary$plate_barcode = plate_barcode
#Export standards data
cat(paste0(Sys.time()," - Saving standards curve data to ",data_root,"\\standards.csv","\n"))
write.csv(std_summary,file = paste0(data_root,"\\standards_N.csv"),row.names=F)
```

Comment: Where's the loop? You should probably be doing this with `lapply`, making sure to `paste` together a unique name for each file.

Comment: *Then when writing the data frame to the csv file, skip the rows from the last one and write after*...what last one? Please show how you need to slice the data frame. Is there a column indicator like group/categ? Number of rows? By index/row.names?

Comment: Thanks got it with append!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, if you want to write rows of the dataframe to a file by *appending*, rather than overwriting the file with each write, you can use `write.table`.

Example:

```
filename <- paste0(data_root,"\\standards_N.csv")
write.table(std_summary[3:4,], file=filename, col.names=F, append=T)
write.table(std_summary[26:30,], file=filename, col.names=F, append=T)
```

***Note:*** you need to set `col.names=F`, otherwise every time you append to file, you'll append another header row in the middle of your dataset.